# php while loop inside for each

Tags: php, loops

i have this code. and i have no idea why the while loop is not working. i can't retrieve the data from course db. please help

**i tried everything but i cant figure out how.**

```
if(isset($_POST['enroll'])){

$n = 0; 
foreach($_POST['trainings'] as $textbox){


    $strpicture = $_POST['strpicture'][$n];
    $stridnumber = $_POST['stridnumber'][$n];
    $strfullname = $_POST['strfullname'][$n];
    $strtraining =$textbox;



    //Add Query to Training Masterlist
    $AddQuery ="INSERT INTO  tms_ml 
    (strpicture,stridnumber,strfullname,strtraining)
   VALUES
   ('$strpicture','$stridnumber','$strfullname','$strtraining')";

    mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);



   $strcoursestat="OPEN";
   //query for training and status training


$SearchCourseQuery = 
        "SELECT strtraining 
        FROM course 
        WHERE strtraining like '%".$strtraining."%' AND strcoursestat like '%".$strcoursestat."%'";

    $resultcoursequery =mysql_query($SearchCourseQuery); 

   require("dbc.php");
   //retrieve data from Course DB
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($resultcoursequery)){ //this is
    echo $sessionnum= $record['strsessnum'];               // the part
                                                            //not working
        };


    $countcourse=mysql_num_rows($resultcoursequery);

    if($countcourse==0){

        echo '</br>' . $strtraining . ' ' . '<b>No Available Schedule for this Training</b>' .'</br>';
    } else{
           echo '</br>' . $strtraining . ' ' . '<b>Enrolled</b>' .'</br>';
            //Add to Training Session

            $test="ab";
            $AddtoSession ="INSERT INTO trn_session(strsessnum)VALUES('$sessionnum')";
            mysql_query($AddtoSession, $con);

    }//else if count       

    $n++;


} // for each
```

**EDITED:** hi guys re create my SEARCH QUERY ($SearchCourseQuery) and it Works Fine now.

```
"SELECT * FROM course where strtraining = '$strtraining' AND strcoursestat = '$strcoursestat'";
```

thank you all for the help!

Comment: check if mysql_fetch_array($resultcoursequery) actually returns anything..maybe it returns an empty array?

Comment: i tried to echo and nothing happens

Comment: Can you make sure that the connections of your mysql are right? And you can insert the first query ($AddQuery)

Comment: yap the first $AddQuery and  $AddtoSession  both executed well and added the data to DB. its just the while loop that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO  tms_ml 
(strpicture,stridnumber,strfullname,strtraining)
VALUES
('$strpicture','$stridnumber',$strfullname','$strtraining')
```

Missing quote at `$strfullname`.

```
INSERT INTO  tms_ml 
(strpicture,stridnumber,strfullname,strtraining)
VALUES
('$strpicture','$stridnumber','$strfullname','$strtraining')
```

Besides that, the mysql* extensions are deprecated and you are vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider to use `PDO` or the `mysqli*` extensions and prepared statements.

Comment: yeap sorry but i just edited the original to post here in stackoverflow. my original code has right quote. yeap i know about mysqli. i just need to finish this project before i move on.

Comment: Then try to print your `$searchCourceQuery` and check if you get a valid query back and use `mysql_error` to check for any mysql errors.

Answer (score 0):

First off;

a foreach in php has an 'index'; which could be determined like so:

```
   foreach ($items as $key => $item)
   {

   }
```

The key is your index (can be named whatever you like) thought that would be a trick worth knowing for you... i.e you don't need to use the $n variable and increment it.

Secondly:

What is `mysql_fetch_array($resultcoursequery)` returning?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($resultcoursequery) will return the value from Course database. which will i pass to add query into trn_session.

Comment: yes of course; but are you getting any results? did you dd your results?

Comment: no and  thats my problem. i tried to echo the  echo $sessionnum= $record['strsessnum']; but it return to no value. so i believe the while is not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You need to add the result_type:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($resultcoursequery, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    echo $sessionnum= $record['strsessnum'];               

};
```